# list oldest employee for each department

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have those two models. I need to return the list of oldest employee for each department.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_day = models.DateField()
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department')

class Department(models.Model):
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I'm a bit stuck about how to make it in Django.

Comment: Is there any more code you can show here? These are just class definitions setting up your models. Your logic on how you are trying to obtain your data would help.

Comment: there is no code more. Assume, that we have several departments with some employees. What would be solution to get them out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is direct query. You need to build list of such employees.

```
empList = []
for dept in Department.objects.all() :
    empList = empList + [dept.employee_set.order_by('birth_day')[0]]

#empList will have list oldest of employees.
```

Comment: Sounds good. I'm stuck about making a direct query. Let see it anybody has comment on your proposal. I hope there is a way to query it directly

Comment: but it will create N+1 query

Answer (score 0):

I think this resolve.

```
empList = []
for dept in Department.objects.all() :
    empList.append(dept.employee_set.latest('birth_day'))
```

**But I was also interested in a better approach, I am thinking of a way to make just one query.**

I have tried it :

```
In [98]: d = Employee.objects.filter().annotate(Min('birth_day'))

In [99]: d.group_by = ['department_id']

In [100]: x = QuerySet(query=d, model=Employee)
(0.001) QUERY = 'SELECT "permissoes_employee"."id", "permissoes_employee"."name", "permissoes_employee"."birth_day", "permissoes_employee"."department_id", MIN("permissoes_employee"."birth_day") AS "birth_day__min" FROM "permissoes_employee" GROUP BY "permissoes_employee"."id", "permissoes_employee"."name", "permissoes_employee"."birth_day", "permissoes_employee"."department_id"' - PARAMS = (); args=()
```

But instead of grouping only by the department, it 'ignores' the group_by and ends by grouping all fields, which ends up generating erroneous results.

I do not think we have a better solution than this, only to make cursor.execute ("SQL")

:(

Comment: this even can be done in terms of list comprehension.

Comment: latest would be youngest, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91875/discussion-between-paulo-pessoa-and-prog-dusan).